# Android GraphicBuffer stride incorrect

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I use android framework's GraphicBuffer to directly get the texture data instead of using glReadPixels to get a speed boost.

I use libjpeg-turbo to compress the GraphicBuffer data into JPEG. But the stride of GraphicBuffer is incorrect in some devices.
For example

```
buf = new GraphicBuffer(buf_width, buf_height, PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888,  GraphicBuffer::USAGE_SW_WRITE_OFTEN | GraphicBuffer::USAGE_HW_TEXTURE);
tjhandle handle = tjInitCompress();
unsigned char* jpeg_buf = NULL;
unsigned long jpeg_size = 0;
int stride = buf->stride; // some devices got 480, some 640.
tjCompress2(handle, save_data, width, stride * tjPixelSize[TJPF_RGBA], height, TJPF_RGBA, &jpeg_buf, &jpeg_size, TJSAMP_420, 80, TJFLAG_BOTTOMUP);
```

in some devices it produces the wrong jpegs.
thanks advance.

Comment: What stride is reported, and what should the value be? What's the color format of the buffer?  Also, how much of a speed boost have you measured? On which devices and which versions of Android?

Comment: I edited the question, the color format is PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888.
For example, if i want a 480X640 buffer, so i pass `buf_width` and `buf_height` respectively 480 and 640.
The stride is **different** in different devices and systems.
Some systems, the stride is the same as `buf_width`, while some don't. The most weird part is in some devices when i got `buf->stride` is 640. So i use the stride as 640 to compress the data into jpeg. i got the incorrect picture!! but if i use 480 as stride, which is the `buf_width`, not the one `buf->stride`, turns out to be the correct picture!!